# MySql and PHP Error Login Remember System

Tags: php, mysql

I will create a Simple Login System and i need to remember the last 5 incorrect login in mysql, but how to create a update loop for 5 login? 
Ex: login incorrect 1:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to the MySQL Server!");
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO login(date,user,ip) VALUES('$today','$_POST['user']','$ip')"
```

Same code for login2, 3,4,5 but after 5 login how to update the first incorrect login? And for 6° incorrect login how to update the 2° incorrect login?

$sql_query = 'UPDATE login SET date="' . $date . etc etc; But

but how do I know the older incorrect login to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to get the correct index. The modulo operation gives you the remainder of the division operation. Assuming to start counting from 0, you need to perform INSERT in [0,1,2,3,4] and then start updating.

Assuming that the **$attempt** variable contains the amount of attempts you can retrieve the index by doing this:

```
$index = $attempt % 5
```

$index will then contain the correct login to update:

```
 5 % 5 = 0
 6 % 5 = 1
 7 % 5 = 2
 8 % 5 = 3
 9 % 5 = 4
10 % 5 = 0
```

Comment: i understand can you explain it pls?

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand? How the modulo operation works or how you can use it to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes how can use and apply in my case? Thanks so much

Comment: I assume you are storing the login attempt counter somewhere you can access it between page reloads (for example in $_SESSION). Let's say that you have this value stored in $_SESSION['attempt']. You can check if $_SESSION['attempt'] < 5 then perform an INSERT (and so $index = $_SESSION['index']), otherwise if $_SESSION['attempt'] is >=5 perform an update (use the modulo operation to retrieve the correct index as I suggested you: $index = $_SESSION['attempt'] % 5). For this to work you need to put the index number also in the mysql table, so change the SQL query to store also the index.

Comment: No, i need insert the total incorrect login for user not for session.. this is my problem, get the old incorrect login for update with the new incorrect login for 5 times on loop

Comment: That's exactly what it does. I obviously assumed that you already check when a login is incorrect or correct. Let's say that you fail the login for the 11th time. In the $_SESSION['attempt'] you have the number 10 (updated on every login failure). Now you have to save a new login failure so you get the index of the oldest saved login failure to overwrite with new data using $index = $_SESSION['attempt'] % 5. Since you are in the 11th attempt, the oldest login is in index 0 and the previous login on index 5 (the modulo will return 0). Then you increment again the $_SESSION['attempt'] variable.